# T-SQL Query: Flattening out a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to build a query to resolve this scenario below:

ParentTable:

```
ParentId  Name
1         Parent A
2         Parent B
```

ChildTable:

```
ChildId   ParentId  Name 
10        1         Child X
11        1         Child Y
12        1         Child Z
13        2         Child Q
```

Where a single parent can be linked to multiple children.  The query then would give the following result:

```
Parent Name    1st-Child   2nd-Child   3rd-Child  4th-Child  5th-Child  
Parent A       Child X     Child Y     Child Z
Parent B       Child Q
```

Is this possible in MS SQL 2008?

Comment: It's possible, but how do you know you will only ever have 5 children?  Why do  you need to denormalize this nicely normalized data?

Comment: There will be data originally in this format (spreadsheet), that is parsed and inserted into the database by another process.  I need to pull that inserted data from the database and mimic what the original file looked like to create a new spreadsheet, so they can verify everything is correct in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you only ever need to list 5 children, this query will work:

```
with T as (
    select P.Name as ParentName,
           C.Name as ChildName,
           row_number() over (partition by P.ParentId order by C.ChildId) as N
    from ParentTable P join ChildTable C on P.ParentId = C.ParentId
) 
select ParentName,
    max(case when N = 1 then ChildName else '' end) as '1st-child',
    max(case when N = 2 then ChildName else '' end) as '2nd-child',
    max(case when N = 3 then ChildName else '' end) as '3rd-child',
    max(case when N = 4 then ChildName else '' end) as '4th-child',
    max(case when N = 5 then ChildName else '' end) as '5th-child'
from T
group by ParentName
```

Comment: I initially had problems getting this to work, but I was missing the partition piece for the row_number().  Works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`PIVOT` was designed for your scenario.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [Parent] = P.Name,
        [Child] = C.Name, 
        [Field] = 'Child ' + LTRIM(STR(
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ParentId ORDER BY C.ChildId)))
    FROM ChildTable C
    JOIN ParentTable P ON P.ParentId = C.ParentId
) A
PIVOT (MAX([Child])
       FOR [Field] IN ([Child 1], [Child 2], [Child 3], [Child 4], [Child 5])) B
```